# Prove that A has a geometric realization in $\mathbb{R}^d.$

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential, simplex

A flag in  a simplical complex K in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is a nested sequence of proper faces, $\sigma_0 < \sigma_1 < ... < \sigma_k$.  The collection of flags forms an abstract simplical complex A sometimes referred to as the order complex of K.  Prove that A has a geometric realization in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

I guess what is confusing me the most is how to deal with the fact that the proper faces are nested.

Comment: Are you having trouble understanding the construction of the order complex?

Comment: Kind of.  I'm just really confused in general.  My professor didn't really go over this in class and assigned homework over it anyway.  I read through the chapter and I'm still really confused.

Comment: Did your professor discuss barycenteric subdivisions? If he did, think about their relation to the problem you have.